# Mapstruct mapper with inheritence

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a **BaseEntity** which has a child named **Customer**
When I make mapper like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {

    Customer toEntity(CustomerDTO model);

    List<Customer> toEntityList(List<CustomerDTO> models);

    CustomerDTO toModel(Customer entity);

    List<CustomerDTO> toModelList(List<Customer> entities);

}
```

BaseEntity fields are not mapped by Mapstruct automatically. Could you tell me please how to do it?

**EDIT:**

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 698399842496839094L;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    protected Long id;


    @Column(nullable = false, length = 36)
    protected String uuid;
}
```

Customer:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Data
publi class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7054669140361044232L;


    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;


    @Column(name = "password_hash", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: This should work. Could you please add source code for 'BaseEntity', 'Customer' and 'CustomerDTO' classes to the question?

Comment: @Sudhir please check my update

Comment: does `CustomerDTO` have `id` and `uuid` fields?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi yes, the same types and the same names

Answer (score 0):

I created a [sample repo](https://github.com/sudhirtumati/mapstruct-test) to demonstrate that everything works as expected. Please compare this with your code and see what is the difference.